# Retrieve Data from DynamoDB asynchronously using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, amazon-dynamodb, jestjs

Following the documentation at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html

I am trying to write a basic test against my DynamoDB tables using promises to handle the asynchronous response with no luck thus far. It should return an object containing the TableNames.

If I access the DynamoDB object without using promises, I have no problem.

This works:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsConfig.json')

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2'})

window.test('Test Connection', () => {
  return dynamo.listTables({Limit: 10}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err', err)
    } else {
      console.log('TableNames are:', data)
    }
    window.expect(data).toEqual(window.expect.anything())
  })
})
```

This does not:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsConfig.json')

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2'})

window.test('Test Connection', () => {
  let tables
  const listPromise = dynamo.listTables({Limit: 10}).promise()
  listPromise.then((data) => {
    tables = data
    console.log('TableNames are:', data)
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  })
  window.expect(tables).toEqual(window.expect.anything())
})
```

The value of data is always undefined. I cannot find any documentation that would indicate that promises are not supported with DynamoDB requests, so I am just about certain that I'm missing something obvious...

Any help is appreciated.  This is my first time asking a question in this forum, so feedback on the question itself is also appreciated.

**EDIT: Problem Solved** - rookie mistake
The issue was not with dynamoDB, but rather with using `test`.  When dealing with promises, the promise must be returned to `test` for proper evaluation.  Otherwise, it cannot be evaluated.

**Working Code:**

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsConfig.json')

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2'})

window.test('Test Connection', () => {
  const listPromise = dynamo.listTables({Limit: 10}).promise()
  return listPromise.then((data) => {
    window.expect(data).toEqual(window.expect.anything())
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  })
})
```

More info: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Thanks to @Brahma Dev for the assistance.

Comment: Move `window.expect` inside `then`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
  
I have your proposed change but the behavior is the same. Unless I'm mistaken, it should not matter because `tables` is defined outside of the promise and should still hold the value of data when `window.expect()`is called.  I also tried using `window.expect(data)` instead of `window.expect(tables)` within `then` with the same result (as one might expect).

This issue has proven more difficult to troubleshoot because the console messages are not working either...

Comment: You're running async code. window.expect will run before dynamodb returns anything. That's why it needs to be inside `then`.

If console.log is not showing anything then that's a completely separate issue. Does your program close instantly ?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That makes perfect sense, and I do recognize that the console issue is another matter. 

So, my assumption that the behavior was the same was false because it was based on the fact that `tables` was still reporting an undefined value. In fact, the test now passes erroneously no matter what conditions I place on it. The program does not exit or error.

Comment: I believe that I may have discovered my problem. I was not implement `test` correctly for promises because I didn't return the promise.
Replacing :
`listPromise.then((data) => {`
with
`return listPromise.then((data) => {`
seems to have solved.

Comment: Returning the promise also cleared up the issue with console logging not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probem with test code, not Promise

The issue was not with dynamoDB or promises, but rather with my use of test. When dealing with promises, the promise must be returned to test for proper evaluation. Otherwise, it cannot be evaluated properly.

Working Code:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./awsConfig.json')

const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: 'us-east-2'})

window.test('Test Connection', () => {
  const listPromise = dynamo.listTables({Limit: 10}).promise()
  return listPromise.then((data) => {
    window.expect(data).toEqual(window.expect.anything())
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  })
})
```

More info: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

Thanks to @Brahma Dev for the assistance.

**EDIT: Corrected working code example based on feedback from @Brahma Dev**
Also, removed some unnecessary variable declarations and assignments.

Comment: You still need to move the `window.expect` into `then` for the actual test.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Copy + paste mistake.  I will make the correction.